# HTML randomInteger() javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call a function that names an inline image using a random number but I cannot figure out how to call it properly.

```
    function showIMG() {

        /*
        The showImg() function displays a random image from the 0.png through 9.png files.
        */

        var imgNumber = randomInteger(9); //Return a random number from 0 to 9.

        <img src='imgNumber.png' alt='' />

    }
```

The call doesn't actually display any of the images that I have 1-9.png. I am fairly certain that I am just calling it incorrectly.

I am also trying to call it later on like so.

```
<script type= "text/javascript"> 
    showIMG;

</script>
```

If you are curious about the randomInteger function:

```
function randomInteger(size) {
return Math.floor((size+1)*Math.random());
}
```

Comment: [Javascript Basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics).

Answer (score 0):

Your `imageNumber` is currently a string; it needs to look like this: `"src="+imageNumber+".png"`

However you have another problem: your `<img>` is in your `<script>`, so it won’t be read at all. You need to have it in your document then edit the src. If you’re using jQuery, it would look like this:

```
$("#imageID").attr("scr",imageNumber+".png");
```

where your `#imageID` is your css ID for your image. You would then just place your image in your html where you want it to go. For the image you'd probably want to have a default src that it's set to in the html then the jquery will just override that src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I had some basic syntax errors as I suspected. I hadn't used an image changer before. New to this, as I imagine you can guess.

This is what I was missing..

```
document.write("<img src=" + imgNumber + ".png />");
```

Comment: I hope you realize that this adds a new image for every random image you generate

Answer (score -1):

Add brackets when calling a function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    showIMG();
</script>
```